# Lua: pass context into loadstring?

Tags: templates, lua, template-engine

I'm trying to pass context into a dynamic expression that I evaluate every iteration of a for loop. I understand that the load string only evaluates within a global context meaning local variables are inaccessible. In my case I work around this limitation by converting a local into a global for the purpose of the string evaluation. Here's what I have:

```
require 'cosmo'

model = { { player = "Cliff", age = 35, gender = "male" }, { player = "Ally", age = 36, gender = "female" }, { player = "Jasmine", age = 13, gender = "female" }, { player = "Lauren", age = 6.5, gender = "female" } }

values = { eval = function(args)
    output = ''
    condition = assert(loadstring('return ' .. args.condition))
    for _, it in ipairs(model) do
        each = it
        if condition() then
            output = output .. each.player .. ' age: ' .. each.age .. ' ' .. '\n'
        end
    end
    return output
end }
template = "$eval{ condition = 'each.age < 30' }"

result = cosmo.fill(template, values)
print (result)
```

My ultimate goal (other than mastering Lua) is to build out an XSLT like tempting engine where I could do something like:

```
apply_templates{ match = each.age > 30}[[<parent-player>$each.player</parent-player>]]

apply_templates{ match = each.age > 30}[[<child-player>$each.player</child-player>]]
```

...And generate different outputs. Currently I'm stuck on my above hawkish means of sharing a local context thru a global. Does anyone here have better insight on how I'd go about doing what I'm attempting to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the context of a function with [`setfenv()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setfenv). This allows you to basically sandbox the loaded function into its own private environment. Something like the following should work:

```
local context = {}
local condition = assert(loadstring('return ' .. args.condition))
setfenv(condition, context)
for _, it in ipairs(model) do
    context['each'] = it
    if condition() then
        -- ...
```

This will also prevent the condition value from being able to access any data you don't want it to, or more crucially, modifying any data you don't want it to. Note, however, that you'll need to expose any top-level bindings into the `context` table that you want `condition` to be able to access (e.g. if you want it to have access to the `math` package then you'll need to stick that into `context`). Alternatively, if you don't have any problem with `condition` having global access and you simply want to deal with not making your local a global, you can use a metatable on `context` to have it pass unknown indexes through to `_G`:

```
setmetatable(context, { __index = _G })
```

Comment: I use something similar in my poor-man's XML element search in my [web data miner](https://github.com/mkottman/wdm/blob/master/wdm.lua#L156).

Answer (score 12):

It's worth noting that [`setfenv` was removed from Lua 5.2 and `loadstring` is deprecated](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.2). 5.2 is pretty new so you won't have to worry about it for a while, but it is possible to write a load routine that works for both versions:

```
local function load_code(code, environment)
    if setfenv and loadstring then
        local f = assert(loadstring(code))
        setfenv(f,environment)
        return f
    else
        return assert(load(code, nil,"t",environment))
    end
end

local context = {}
context.string = string
context.table = table
-- etc. add libraries/functions that are safe for your application.
-- see: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes
local condition = load_code("return " .. args.condition, context)
```

Version 5.2's [`load`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) handles both the old [`loadstring`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) behavior and sets the environment (context, in your example). Version 5.2 also changes the concept of [environments](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.2), so `loadstring` may be the least of your worries. Still, it's something to consider to possibly save yourself some work down the road.

Comment: Thanks Corbin! :) While I'm currently working on 5.1 I was originally assuming a 5.2 environment. This should definitely save me some headaches!